# Performance about query result of union

Tags: sql, performance, optimization, query-optimization, union

I have two tables storing user data, one for internal users, another for external users. Both users will buy a book, so I had below sql script

```
select o.orderid, o.orderdate, u.firstname, u.lastname from OrderTable o inner join 
(
  select inneruser_id as uid, firstname, lastname from innerUser where len(firstname) > 0 or len(lastname) > 0
  union
  select external_id as uid, firstname, lastname from externalUser where len(firstname) > 0 or len(lastname) > 0
) u on u.uid = o.userId where o.orderdate > {0}
```

For table innerUser, innneruser_id is primary key, but external_id is not the primary key of externalUser table,  I want to know, if the result of union still has index on u.uid, because there are over 200,000 internal users and about 100,000 external users.

Do I need to add index to external_id, will this improve the performance of the query.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run your query in management studio, with "Include Actual Execution Plan" option turned On.

and do what it suggests to imporove performance.

Comment: That is very very helpful, I just use the recommended "missing index" to highly improved the query performance. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might, but it looks like adding an index to `u.uid`, `o.userId`, and `o.orderdate` is more likely to improve performance, since those are involved in the join and the filtering.